# C language char pointer variable value to non pointer char array value?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I im writing one program in gcc that decodes base64 encoded string.

I don't know how to assign value from mycustomvariable to array.

Example: this works:

```
char myb64[1024] = "TXkgYm9ubmllIGlzIG92ZXIgdGhlICAgICAgICAgIA==";
char mydst[1024] = "";
```

But i need to assign value from my mycustomstring variable to myb64[1024]. So i write this and i get error when compiling: error: invalid initializer
    char myb64[1024] = mycustomstring;
    ^

```
char *mycustomstring = "TXkgYm9ubmllIGlzIG92ZXIgdGhlICAgICAgICAgIA==";
char myb64[1024] = mycustomstring;
char mydst[1024] = "";
```

How can i assign value from mycustomstring to myb64[1024] array? I need to have *mycustomstring because this is taken from url and query.

Comment: It depends. What's the type of `mycustomstring`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to copy the contents of `mycustomstring` to `myb64`. `strcpy` is the function that does that. E.g.

```
char *mycustomstring = "TXkgYm9ubmllIGlzIG92ZXIgdGhlICAgICAgICAgIA==";
char myb64[1024];
strcpy(myb64, mycustomstring);
```

Comment: Thanks. That i need...so if i get right....string and any type can be converted using strcpy...so if for example i have in memoriy int i can get using strcpy copy integer from memory to char variable. PHP have easy manupalation with strings and variables..but i now get the point. I im novice in c programming...thanks for ansewer.

Comment: No. `strcpy` performs No conversion. It simply copies a nul-terminated *string* from *source* to *dest* (*dest* must have sufficient space to hold *source* + the nul-terminating char). To copy an integer to a string, you must convert the integer to its ASCII representation. Look at `sprintf` (or `strtol` or `atoi` and then `strcpy`).

Comment: strcpy expects null terminated char arrays. You would need memcpy to copy a number of bytes representing an int. Both functions copy raw bytes and perform no conversion